# Asterisk DIALSTATUS returns null

Tags: java, asterisk, asterisk-java

I'm using Asterisk-Java to work with my Asterisk server. In my AGI script, I'd like to wait for the call to be answered to answer on the AGI side. To do this, I'd like to use the [`DIALSTATUS` channel variable](https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-variable-dialstatus/). Though

```
System.out.println("DIALSTATUS is: " + channel.getVariable("DIALSTATUS"));
```

Doing this always prints `null`, wherever in the AGI script I put it.

Please suggest I you have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

DIALSTATUS variable active only after Dial call.

Comment: Isn't that called when I originate a call?

Comment: No idea. Never checked. You always can do originate to Local/, will be dialplan.

Comment: People, please not create new dialler cores. Use already writed like vicidial one. There are REALLY alot of issues in dooing such core.